# Fix lag in socket.io multiplayer game

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, socket.io, server

i'm trying to reproduce a simple game in multiplayer (max 2 players).I'm using javascript,node.js,socket.io and express to do that.
It was all good but from when i activated the main cycle in the server and in the clients the game begin so fluid but after 2 or 3 second the lag and the freeze increase exponentially. I know that this is for the infinity of event listener that i call in the infinite cycles.....How can i avoid that?

Here's the cycle of the server:

```
function updateGameArea(){

    frameNo+=1;  
    if (players.length < 2){
            if (players[0]!=socket.id){
                console.log('Logged',socket.id);
                players.push(socket.id);
            }

    }
    for (i=0;i<players.length;i++){
        if (socket.id==players[i]){

            var c=i;
        }
    }
    if (!id1 || !id0){
    socket.emit('id',{'id':c});
    }




    socket.on('info',(data)=>{

        if (data.c==0){

            myGamePiece=data.x;
            info0=true;
        }
        else {

            yourGamePiece=data.x;
            info1=true;
        }
    })

    socket.on('id0',()=>{
        id0=true;

    })

    socket.on('id1',()=>{

        id1=true;
    })


    if (id0 & id1 & info0 & info1){
    socket.emit('go');
    socket.emit('frame',{'f':frameNo});
    socket.on('newpos',(data)=>{
        console.log('Wroking');
        if (data.c==0){
            myGamePiece.newPos();
            socket.emit('info0',{'o':myGamePiece.gravitySpeed,'x':myGamePiece.x,'y':myGamePiece.y,'sy':myGamePiece.speedY});
        }
        else if(data.c==1){
            yourGamePiece.newPos();
            socket.emit('info1',{'o':yourGamePiece.gravitySpeed,'x':yourGamePiece.x,'y':yourGamePiece.y,'sy':yourGamePiece.speedY});
        }
    })

    socket.on('numob',(data)=>{
       myObstacles[myObstacles.length-1]=data.i;
       myObstacles[myObstacles.length-1]=data.l;
    })

    if (frameNo ==1 || everyinterval(150)){
        socket.emit('createob');                          
    }

    for (i=0;i<myObstacles.length;i+=1){
        myObstacles[i].x += -1 ;
        socket.emit('agobj',{'i':i});
    }

    for (i=0;i<myObstacles.length; i+=1){
        if (myGamePiece.crashWith(myObstacles[i])){
            socket.emit('dead0');
        }
        else if(yourGamePiece.crashWith(myObstacles[i])){
            socket.emit('dead1');
        }   
    }


    socket.on('push',(data)=>{
        var l=speed(data.id);
        if (l=0){
            var id=0;
            y=-3.5
            socket.emit('pushinf',{'y':y,'id':id})
        }
        else{
           var  id=1;
            y=-3.5;
            socket.emit('pushinf',{'y':y,'id':id})
        }
    })

    socket.on('disconnect',() => {
        console.log('id attivo',socket.id);
        console.log('disconnected!',socket.id);
        for (i=0;i<players.length;i++){
            if (players[i]==socket.id){
                players.splice(i,1);
            }   
        }

    });
}
```

Here's the client cycle:

```
function updateGameArea(){

    socket.on('connect', function() {
            console.log("connected from the client side");
    });

    socket.on('id',function(data){
        console.log('server sent info id to me')
      console.log(data.id)
        var id=data.id;
        console.log(id);
        if (id==0){
        socket.emit('id0');
        }
        else {
            socket.emit('id1');
        }   
        socket.emit('info',{'x':myGamePiece,'c':id});
    });
    socket.on('go',function(){
        go=true;
    })
    if (go){
            socket.on('frame',function(data){
                frameNo=data.f;
            })
            socket.on('createob',function(){
              x=myGameArea.canvas.width;
              minHeight=60;
              maxHeight=140;
              height=Math.floor(Math.random()*(maxHeight-minHeight+1)+minHeight);
              minGap=60;
              maxGap=90;
              var gap=Math.floor(Math.random()*(maxGap-minGap+1)+minGap);     
              myObstacles.push(new component(10,height,"green",x,0));
              myObstacles.push(new component(10,x-height-gap,"green",x,height + gap));
              socket.emit('numob',{'l':myObstacles[myObstacles.length],'i':myObstacles[myObstacles.length-1]})
             });
            socket.emit('newpos',{'c':id});
            socket.on('info0',function(data){
                if (id==0){
                    myGamePiece.gravitySpeed=data.o
                    myGamePiece.x=data.x;
                    myGamePiece.y=data.y;
                    myGamePiece.speedY=data.sy;
                }
                else{
                  yourGamePiece.gravitySpeed=data.o;
                  yourGamePiece.x=data.x;
                  yourGamePiece.y=data.y;
                  yourGamePiece.speedY=data.sy;
                }
            })
            socket.on('info1',function(data){
              if (id==1){
                    myGamePiece.gravitySpeed=data.o;
                    myGamePiece.x=data.x;
                    myGamePiece.y=data.y;
                    myGamePiece.speedY=data.sy;
                }
                else{
                  yourGamePiece.gravitySpeed=data.o;
                  yourGamePiece.x=data.x;
                  yourGamePiece.y=data.y;
                  yourGamePiece.speedY=data.sy;
                }
            })

            socket.on('dead0',function(){
              if (id==0){
                myGameArea.stop();
                mySound.play();
                GameO=true;
              }
              else{
                mySound.play();
                yourGamePiece.gravitySpeed==3.5;
              }
            })
            socket.on('dead1',function(){
              if (id==1){
                myGameArea.stop();
                mySound.play();
                GameO=true;
              }
              else{
                mySound.play();
                yourGamePiece.gravitySpeed==3.5;
              }
            })
            socket.on('agobj',function(data){
              myObstacles[data.i].x+=1;
            })
            myGameArea.canvas.addEventListener('click',function(){
              socket.emit('push',{'id':id});
              if (mSoundw.sound.pausedy) {
                        mySoundw.sound.play();
                    }
                    else{
                        mySoundw.sound.currentTime = 0
                    }

              socket.on('pushinf',function(data){
                    if (id==data.c){
                          myGamePiece.gravitySpeed=y;
                          myGamePiece.image.src="angry.png";
                    }
                    else{
                          yourGamePiece.gravitySpeed=y;
                          yourGamePiece.image.src="angryb.png";
                    }
              })
            },false)
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Like you said yourself, at first sight, my opinion is that the listeners might be the culprits. If updateGameArea() on the client side is the method repeated to update the game, every time the update happens, you are adding a listener to the socket event. Which is, after for ex. 5 iterations through that update method, if one message arrives through the socket, it runs the dedicated code 5 times.

You only need to tell once to the socket how it should handle a certain message (same for any listener), and you can do that at setup, no need to run it over and over with the loop.

Here's an attempt at refactoring the code you've posted to go along with what I'm saying. Notice how I use booleans or other variables when a message is received on the client side to alert the updateGameArea() method that some task needs to be performed (after which task the boolean/variable resets and waits for the message again if necessary).

This is assuming that you already have initialized a variable 'socket'.

Hope I didn't break anything.

```
var id = null;//as long as it's null, no message is emitted from the client
var go;
var createob = false;
var clicked = false;

socket.on('connect', function() {
    console.log("connected from the client side");
});

socket.on('id',function(data){
    console.log('server sent info id to me')
    console.log(data.id)
    id = data.id;//set the id
    console.log(id);
});

socket.on('go',function(){
    go = true;
});

socket.on('frame',function(data){
    if (go) {
        frameNo=data.f;
    }
});

socket.on('createob',function(){
    if (go) {
        createob = true;
    }
});

socket.on('info0',function(data){
    if (id==0){
        myGamePiece.gravitySpeed=data.o
        myGamePiece.x=data.x;
        myGamePiece.y=data.y;
        myGamePiece.speedY=data.sy;
    }
    else{
        yourGamePiece.gravitySpeed=data.o;
        yourGamePiece.x=data.x;
        yourGamePiece.y=data.y;
        yourGamePiece.speedY=data.sy;
    }
});

socket.on('info1',function(data){
    if (id==1){
          myGamePiece.gravitySpeed=data.o;
          myGamePiece.x=data.x;
          myGamePiece.y=data.y;
          myGamePiece.speedY=data.sy;
      }
      else{
          yourGamePiece.gravitySpeed=data.o;
          yourGamePiece.x=data.x;
          yourGamePiece.y=data.y;
          yourGamePiece.speedY=data.sy;
      }
});


socket.on('dead0',function(){
    if (id==0){
        myGameArea.stop();
        mySound.play();
        GameO=true;
    }
    else{
        mySound.play();
        yourGamePiece.gravitySpeed==3.5;
    }
});

socket.on('dead1',function(){
    if (id==1){
        myGameArea.stop();
        mySound.play();
        GameO=true;
    }
    else{
        mySound.play();
        yourGamePiece.gravitySpeed==3.5;
    }
});

socket.on('agobj',function(data){
    myObstacles[data.i].x+=1;
});

myGameArea.canvas.addEventListener('click',function(){
    clicked = true;
    socket.emit('push',{'id':id});
    if (mSoundw.sound.pausedy) {
        mySoundw.sound.play();
    }
    else{
        mySoundw.sound.currentTime = 0
    }
},false);

socket.on('pushinf',function(data){
    if (clicked) {//I was not sure if you need this to run only when there's been click. If it's independent of the click then remove this condition and the 'clicked = false' below
        if (id==data.c){
              myGamePiece.gravitySpeed=y;
              myGamePiece.image.src="angry.png";
        }
        else{
              yourGamePiece.gravitySpeed=y;
              yourGamePiece.image.src="angryb.png";
        }
        clicked = false;
    }  
})

function updateGameArea(){
    //whenever the 'id' message from the server arrives, it sets the id;
    //whenever the game updates again it sees a non-null id and emits the
    //corresponding message below, then sets the id to null again
    if (id != null) {
        if (id==0){
            socket.emit('id0');
        }
        else {
            socket.emit('id1');
        }   
        socket.emit('info',{'x':myGamePiece,'c':id});
        id = null;
    }


    if (go){
        if (createob) {
            x=myGameArea.canvas.width;
            minHeight=60;
            maxHeight=140;
            height=Math.floor(Math.random()*(maxHeight-minHeight+1)+minHeight);
            minGap=60;
            maxGap=90;
            var gap=Math.floor(Math.random()*(maxGap-minGap+1)+minGap);     
            myObstacles.push(new component(10,height,"green",x,0));
            myObstacles.push(new component(10,x-height-gap,"green",x,height + gap));
            socket.emit('numob',{'l':myObstacles[myObstacles.length],'i':myObstacles[myObstacles.length-1]})

            /*
            Depending on if you only want this body to be executed if and only if the 'createob' message has been received,
            you may want to reinitialize the boolean
            */
            createob = false;//comment this out if this body should run from the moment the message is received until further in the game, without depending on the createob message.
        }
        socket.emit('newpos',{'c':id});
    }
}
```